# Mysql Unknown column on view

Tags: php, mysql

Im having a bad time trying to understand how Views, Unions and joins works,

I have this view:

```
SELECT
 id,
 CODE,
 NAME,
 type,
 quantity
FROM
 items
UNION ALL
 SELECT
    id,
    CODE,
    NAME,
    type,
    price,
    quantity
FROM
    inventory_items
```

The table items doesnt have a column named quantity, but i still need to get that value from inventory_items, if i remove the select on quantity from items i get:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that
>       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near FROM items

If i leave the select i get:

> [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'quantity' in field list'

What exactly am I trying to accomplish? i want to select all data from those tables using unique columns, i dont want like name1,name2 columns etc.

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: the column in not in the table. The column is not in the view. Depending on the angle of the error

Comment: With union you must use same columns in both. You have to add to union price
SELECT
 id,
 CODE,
 NAME,
 type,
 price
 quantity
FROM
 items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UNION expects the same number of columns in each set of results. If you have a column that will always be empty, you can simply select NULL instead of a real column. Note that the column names are taken from the first SELECT, so you will need to add an alias for your NULL (or just switch the SELECTs around)

```
SELECT
 id,
 CODE,
 NAME,
 type,
 NULL AS price,
 NULL AS quantity
FROM
 items
UNION ALL
 SELECT
    id,
    CODE,
    NAME,
    type,
    price,
    quantity
FROM
    inventory_items
```

Comment: It worked, i have to wait 10 min for chosing this as the right answer.

Comment: When you say, switch the select around, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I just mean that you could do the inventory_items query first. It's just to avoid having to add the `AS quantity`. It doesn't really matter either way.